# java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: url=null Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying the following simple code, which works as per expectation on my localmachine

```
public class NewTest 
{

  @Test
  public void f() throws IOException
  {   

  Properties obj = new Properties();
  FileInputStream fileobj = new FileInputStream("C:\\selenium_Automation\\data_links.properties");
  obj.load(fileobj);

  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get(obj.getProperty("crm_url"));

  System.out.println("Complete");
  }

}
```

but when i try the same code on a different machine i get the following

```
 FAILED: f
 java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: url=null
at com.google.common.collect.CollectPreconditions.checkEntryNotNull(CollectPreconditions.java:33)
at com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableBiMap.<init>(SingletonImmutableBiMap.java:39)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableBiMap.of(ImmutableBiMap.java:57)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(ImmutableMap.java:80)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:306)
```

The code works fine if i replace (obj.getProperty("crm_url")) with the actual URL, but i have several different links stored in the properties file and i need them to be read from that place. **What i am doing wrong can some please tell me the reason behind the NUll pointer expection for the URL**

Answer (score 4):

This is the error you get when you try to add a `null` object to an immutable map in the google common library. My guess would be that the `org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get` is attempting to find do that and your file path is null or something similar. I would check the url but that is only a guess.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I would say that the location of your properties file is different on the other machine.

Comment: Thank you for the response, i use several different properties from the file, and they all work fine, it is only when i try to naviagate to a specific URL is when it throws a Null pointer error message

Comment: So to understand this better, are you saying on the other machine, also fetching properties from file works. Only for a specific property, you see this error? Can you also share the content of the properties file and point out which works and which does not work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here I can assume is that the url you are using in the properties file must be wrong or it might have the inverted commas. If it has the inverted commas i.e
url="https://www.google.com" then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the location of properties file is correct wherever you are utilizing it e.g. in case of FileInputStream

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Even I had faced this issue. I deleted the target folder before running the code and my issue was resolved.